# Получение http-запроса

Tags: xcode, http, objective-c, ios, iphone

У меня в приложении несколько методов, которые отправляют http-запрос на сервер.

Как при получении ответа от сервера ( в `connectionDidFinishLoading` )  узнать какой метод отправил запрос? На все запросы от сервера получаю json с одинаковой структурой.

Реализуется ли такое с помощью встроенных средств Objective-C? Или нужно использовать встроенные библиотеки?

Спасибо за помощь.

Comment: отбой пацаны. оказывается все делается через AFNetworking. Мега-крутая вещь!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Да конечно возможно, например если вы пишете под iOS 7 может помочь `NSURLSessionDataTask`, реализация через блоки:

```
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [self.requestSerializer requestWithMethod:@"POST" URLString:[[NSURL URLWithString:URLString relativeToURL:self.baseURL] absoluteString] parameters:parameters];

NSURLSessionDataTask *task = [self dataTaskWithRequest:request completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse * response, id responseObject, NSError *error) {
        if (error) {

        } else {

        }
    }];
```

лучше всего использовать AFNetworking - мощный инструмент для работы с запросами
https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking